# Could not able to resolve why the EAR file could not be deployed in Weblogic 10.3?

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, ear

The error is coming 
**Deployment connection was released before the state of deployment was known.**

Is it error of timeout or do i have to change some settings

Answer (score 0):

Start with checking the server logs, they should contain useful informations about what went wrong. If the errors you'll find in there don't help, post them.